# Xamarin Live Reload - Compile error missing Plugin.DeviceInfo.Abstractions

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, livereload

I'm trying to use this tool to improve design productivity but cannot get it to compile.

After adding this to my application as per the installation instructions I'm getting this compiler error:

> Can not resolve reference: `Plugin.DeviceInfo.Abstractions`,
>   referenced by `Xamarin.Live.Reload`. Please add a NuGet package or
>   assembly reference for `Plugin.DeviceInfo.Abstractions`, or remove the
>   reference to `Xamarin.Live.Reload`

All my projects already reference Xam.Plugins.DeviceInfo which is where that namespace lives. And I can see the dependency Reload wants is satisfied in VS but compile still fails.

Not sure what to try to fix this error. Has anyone seen this error and fixed it?

Comment: Did you add the package from NuGet?

Comment: No, it turned out that this issue was caused by Live Reload needed DeviceInfo v3.1 not the latest 4.0.0.13 ...

Comment: The LiveReload NuGet is installed to your local cache ... when looking for it in the package manager make sure your NuGet feeds source is set to All.

Comment: Alternatively you could take a look at this https://www.twitch.tv/videos/441875218